# unable to bind map geocoordinate center on to map on windows phone through mvvm using bing maps

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I am trying to set the center property of map control dynamically based on the various routes that I display on the map at a given instance. I am using startpoint for the route as a geocoordinate center here. To achieve this I tried to bind the geocoordinate center on to the map control through mvvm on windows phone application using bing maps. I am able to get the data for center location with latitiude and longitude but unable to bind it to UI(xaml) page.

the following is my RouteViewModel class

```
 private Location startPoint;
    public Location StartPoint
    {
        get { return startPoint; }
        set
        {
            startPoint = value;
            Change("StartPoint");
        }
    }

   private System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate centre;

    public System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate Centre
    {
        get { return centre; }
        set { centre = value; }
    }

    private string getcenter;

    public string Getcenter
    {
        get { return getcenter; }
        set { getcenter = value; }
    }

    private Location endPoint;
    public Location EndPoint
    {
        get { return endPoint; }
        set
        {
            endPoint = value;
            Change("EndPoint");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Location> routePoints;
    public ObservableCollection<Location> RoutePoints
    {
        get { return routePoints; }
        set
        {
            routePoints = value;
            Change("RoutePoints");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ItineraryItem> itinerary;
    public ObservableCollection<ItineraryItem> Itinerary
    {
        get
        {
            return itinerary;
        }
        set
        {
            itinerary = value;
            Change("Itinerary");
        }
    }


   private void LocationLoaded()
    {
        if (fromLocation != null && toLocation != null)
        {
            var fromWaypoint = new Waypoint();
            fromWaypoint.Description = "From";
            fromWaypoint.Location = new Location();
            fromWaypoint.Location.Altitude = fromLocation.Altitude;
            fromWaypoint.Location.Latitude = fromLocation.Latitude;
            fromWaypoint.Location.Longitude = fromLocation.Longitude;

            var toWaypoint = new Waypoint();
            toWaypoint.Description = "To";
            toWaypoint.Location = new Location();
            toWaypoint.Location.Altitude = toLocation.Altitude;
            toWaypoint.Location.Latitude = toLocation.Latitude;
            toWaypoint.Location.Longitude = toLocation.Longitude;

            var routeRequest = new RouteRequest();
            routeRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
            routeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = App.BingApiKey;
            routeRequest.Waypoints = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Waypoint>();
            routeRequest.Waypoints.Add(fromWaypoint);
            routeRequest.Waypoints.Add(toWaypoint);
            routeRequest.Options = new RouteOptions();
            routeRequest.Options.RoutePathType = RoutePathType.Points;
            routeRequest.UserProfile = new Utils.WP7.Bing.BingRoute.UserProfile();
            routeRequest.UserProfile.DistanceUnit = Utils.WP7.Bing.BingRoute.DistanceUnit.Kilometer;

            var routeClient = new RouteServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService");
            routeClient.CalculateRouteCompleted += new EventHandler<CalculateRouteCompletedEventArgs>(OnRouteComplete);
            routeClient.CalculateRouteAsync(routeRequest);
        }
    }


   private void OnRouteComplete(object sender, CalculateRouteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Result != null && e.Result.Result.Legs != null & e.Result.Result.Legs.Any())
        {
            var result = e.Result.Result;
            var legs = result.Legs.FirstOrDefault();

            StartPoint = legs.ActualStart;
            EndPoint = legs.ActualEnd;
            RoutePoints = result.RoutePath.Points;
            Itinerary = legs.Itinerary;

     //Centre = StartPoint;
             Getcenter = string.Format("{0},{1}", StartPoint.Latitude.ToString(), StartPoint.Longitude.ToString());

            RaiseRouteResolved();
        }
     }
```

the following is the code in my .xaml.cs page and later is the code in my xaml page.

```
 (DataContext as RouteViewModel).ResolveRouteFromCurrent();



<maps:Map x:Name="RMaps" Center="{Binding Getcenter}" ZoomLevel="5" CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MapCredentials}">
```

I have also tried binding "Centre"(commented in above code) of type GeoCoordinate, but that does not resolve my issue. Can some one please let me know the way I'd be able to resolve this...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and your `Getcenter` property needs to raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` when the value changes for databinding to work when the value updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then it does not resolve the thing. another issue is that I am unable to set the zoom level to the map once the route is set to the center...can you please let me know the way to get that...thanks again.

Comment: Add another property (that again raises the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event) and bind the `ZoomLevel` to it

Comment: Actually I want to set the zoomlevel dynamically based on the routes  that may vary in distance for different routes..i.e.,long or short and which can not have the zoomlevel as same for all routes. So, Is there any way to achieve it...if yes, please let me know...thanks.

Comment: In which case you can [ask the map to zoom to fit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10828906/50447)