# windows phone map control show all locations (zoom to include all pushpins)

Tags: location, zooming, windows-phone, bing

I've tried using 
    map.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations));

But the thing is I need the all the pushpins to be shown as well. Using the above method only takes the location into account. Some pushpins gets cropped especially corner ones.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(locations)` gives you the binding box of the locations, so you could artificially inflate that a little (for example, by adding/subtracting a tenth of a degree from each edge) before passing it to `SetView`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can increase the zoom level of map so that pushpins will be visible...
try this.
map1.ZoomLevel = 5;
```